# I have difficulties creating a dialog box

Tags: winapi, dialog

I really do not know what i am doing wrong.
I would like to create a dialogbox.

It is just does not show.

Declaration

```
BOOL CALLBACK NewDlgProc(HWND main, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
```

Diagproc:

```
BOOL CALLBACK NewDlgProc(HWND main, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {

        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

In windproc wm_command:

```
case ID_MENU_NEW:
{
    int NewDlg = DialogBox(GetModuleHandle(NULL),                        
                           MAKEINTRESOURCE(ID_DIALOG_NEW), main, NewDlgProc);

    if(NewDlg == 0)
      MessageBox(main, "Cannot create dialogbox", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
}
break;
```

resource.h:

```
#define ID_DIALOG_NEW   201
```

dlg.rc

```
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"

ID_DIALOG_NEW DIALOG DISCARDABLE 100,100, 100,100
STYLE DS_MODALFRAME | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Add new"
FONT 8, "Ms Sans Serif"
BEGIN
END
```

Comment: You didn't check for -1 as return value. Also, check the msdn documentation on DialogBox, there is a point with typical failure reasons.

Comment: Actually. the thing i do not know what is going on is that i deleted a recent project, (where these dlgboxes were working) but I saved some of my code in individual files. I created a new project, made new files, copy-pasted the code and now it fails.

Comment: Did you add dlg.rc to the project ? If dlg.rc is not compiled, it won't work. And you should check `NewDlg == -1` if you really want to show an error message. In your case `NewDlg` is certainly -1.

Comment: I changed it to `if(NewDlg == -1)` and now it pops up the error messagebox. The other thing is I always add a file first and then write the code in it so the file is in project already.

Comment: With windows api you can create a message box (if that is wanted in this case,) by `MessageBox(0, "body", "title", 0);`

Answer (score 0):

A dialog can have an owner or be unowned, but it cannot have a parent. Consequently, you cannot have the `WS_CHILD` window style for a dialog. Replace that with `WS_POPUP`, and everyone will be happy.

Relevant quote from the MSDN ([About Dialog Boxes : Modal Dialog Boxes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644994.aspx#modal_boxes)):

> An application must not create a modal dialog box having the **WS_CHILD** style.

Comment: @Frank: Is your `NewDlgProc` and dialog resource compiled into a DLL? If so, you'll need to pass the correct module handle to your call of `DialogBox`. You can also open the module where the dialog resource resides in Visual Studio, and verify in the resource editor, that the dialog template resource is actually there.

Comment: No. Im not using DLL files. and im using codeblocks.

Comment: @Frank: I doubt that it makes a difference, but the [DIALOG resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381003.aspx) is obsolete. Use a [DIALOGEX resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381002.aspx) instead. As for Code::Blocks: It's best not used for being a notoriously poor IDE.

Answer (score 0):

How come in your dialog procedure you are not calling DefDlgProc() for the messages you are not handling?

```
BOOL CALLBACK NewDlgProc(HWND main, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {

        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefDlgProc(main, msg, wParam, lParam); // need default processing!!!!!!!!!!
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: [DefDlgProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645450.aspx): *"The DefDlgProc function must not be called by a dialog box procedure; doing so results in recursive execution."* `DefDlgProc` is provided for applications that register their own dialog classes. This is not the case here, and default processing takes place, if the [DialogProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx) returns `FALSE`.